# Android How to store a big integer with shared preferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, biginteger

*Just like the title said: how do you store a big integer with shared preferences in android?*

```
Big integer i;
public static void loadI() {
    cash = prefs.get...?("", i);
}

public static void saveI() {
    editor.put...?("", i);

}
```

Comment: Convert the `BigInteger` to a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
public static void loadI() {
    i = new BigInteger(prefs.getString("I", "0"));
}

public static void saveI() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("I", i.toString());
    editor.apply();
}
```